# MySQL - Calling batch file to run MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a MySQL table (`users.sql`) and randomly generated data (`randomdatausers.sql`).

```
users.sql:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'John','Smith','344','johnsmith@gmail.com'),(2,'Michele','Lipton','122','michelelipton@gmail.com'),(3,'Dustin','Bara','232','dustinbara@gmail.com');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2018-02-25  8:37:13

randomdatausers.sql

#
# TABLE STRUCTURE FOR: users
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (1, 'Akeem', 'Wolff', '+18(6)5124902377', 'rgorczany@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (2, 'Crystel', 'Murphy', '758-669-5095x989', 'luciano17@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (3, 'Lily', 'Schiller', '01338530479', 'lstreich@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (4, 'Leda', 'Torphy', '1-048-776-2005x60915', 'albin36@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (5, 'Lucious', 'Casper', '1-773-869-3803', 'watsica.edgardo@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (6, 'Flavie', 'Gleichner', '651.029.8822', 'brennan.greenholt@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (7, 'Helena', 'Hodkiewicz', '+45(3)3008077178', 'abbey.watsica@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (8, 'Andre', 'Reinger', '(882)309-4032', 'briana.collier@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (9, 'Manuel', 'Shanahan', '(689)313-8722x042', 'margret07@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (10, 'Rudy', 'Daugherty', '584.688.2013', 'elenor.heidenreich@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (11, 'Harry', 'Lemke', '04771350512', 'adela67@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (12, 'Kiel', 'Carter', '259.247.9163', 'layne.roob@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (13, 'Lavern', 'Kihn', '+37(6)4202422515', 'kenyon89@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (14, 'Marion', 'Wehner', '1-006-093-7948', 'xmurray@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (15, 'Nikita', 'Strosin', '1-429-160-2393x02463', 'drake.balistreri@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (16, 'Carson', 'Yost', '1-223-193-9428', 'ksmith@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (17, 'Lucile', 'Keeling', '(534)273-7805', 'mertz.sibyl@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (18, 'Ellen', 'Denesik', '482.180.2447x71668', 'tracey.mcdermott@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (19, 'Oleta', 'Greenholt', '722-480-0976x20816', 'providenci.kulas@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (20, 'Taylor', 'Mraz', '00417637834', 'moshe12@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (21, 'Lamar', 'Kub', '931-311-0128x895', 'uauer@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (22, 'Camila', 'Howe', '09329179704', 'jerod82@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (23, 'Nigel', 'Ritchie', '1-065-925-9144x11983', 'ledner.grover@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (24, 'Mittie', 'Emard', '(882)921-3430', 'ophelia85@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (25, 'Laurianne', 'Abshire', '095-878-4590x5213', 'eleonore59@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (26, 'Unique', 'Romaguera', '+26(9)9262027820', 'reymundo11@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (27, 'Kenya', 'Rippin', '171.387.8695', 'fheller@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (28, 'Marcelle', 'Cassin', '+27(2)8330911181', 'uhomenick@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (29, 'Junior', 'Botsford', '367.060.3888x6349', 'greenfelder.emmett@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (30, 'Nicolette', 'Fay', '692-041-9800x1470', 'bthiel@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (31, 'Danyka', 'Bradtke', '283.433.4910', 'oschoen@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (32, 'Davion', 'Larson', '219.280.8998', 'ygreenfelder@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (33, 'Bette', 'Nicolas', '342-958-8259x73464', 'kuhic.theron@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (34, 'Ron', 'Beier', '(966)781-8270', 'serena.klein@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (35, 'Kurtis', 'Mills', '538.273.1339x2716', 'deborah.schamberger@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (36, 'Tyrell', 'Willms', '1-658-299-9320', 'hgreen@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (37, 'Isobel', 'Frami', '507-179-3870', 'schneider.lessie@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (38, 'Calista', 'Rippin', '+26(3)2963407534', 'laverne.marquardt@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (39, 'Jewell', 'Sanford', '(471)795-8250', 'pkoss@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (40, 'Efren', 'Rippin', '400-196-2345', 'lspencer@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (41, 'Pink', 'Hammes', '045.812.0487x407', 'auer.orlo@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (42, 'Roxanne', 'Jacobs', '1-701-661-5919x90672', 'qkunde@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (43, 'Adeline', 'Carter', '1-302-504-7514x121', 'cristal64@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (44, 'Mayra', 'Stark', '+48(1)6227278654', 'buddy79@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (45, 'Hortense', 'Barrows', '(953)392-3360x44711', 'gerry.nikolaus@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (46, 'Monserrate', 'Doyle', '747-948-4442x403', 'evalyn.runolfsdottir@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (47, 'Fernando', 'Kshlerin', '1-992-697-7369x9558', 'fmitchell@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (48, 'Angela', 'Kunde', '533-170-0667x56908', 'malcolm.bechtelar@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (49, 'Maurine', 'Fadel', '594-069-5754x1025', 'tfranecki@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (50, 'Jalyn', 'Weber', '1-391-610-7036x5316', 'lkris@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (51, 'Keely', 'Cremin', '016-150-0220x178', 'ecrooks@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (52, 'Robb', 'Bashirian', '173-248-5533', 'koelpin.samson@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (53, 'Flo', 'Stiedemann', '1-599-729-2922x65722', 'keeling.nikita@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (54, 'Elisabeth', 'Blanda', '1-738-830-9427x1532', 'lowe.micaela@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (55, 'Caden', 'Bradtke', '169-921-4894', 'dstoltenberg@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (56, 'Ken', 'Mertz', '+67(2)5754199238', 'hyatt.lexie@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (57, 'Valerie', 'Weissnat', '(726)108-8598x71544', 'kacie.bogisich@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (58, 'Dee', 'Prohaska', '379-610-3543x38650', 'harold.fadel@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (59, 'Alfred', 'Bartell', '+23(7)4884096567', 'lacy.schumm@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (60, 'Tyler', 'Durgan', '1-358-940-6815', 'xrowe@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (61, 'Jakayla', 'Bauch', '01348594003', 'mathias.terry@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (62, 'Earline', 'Torphy', '(183)076-3649', 'michaela33@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (63, 'Madyson', 'Macejkovic', '944-393-0322', 'sherman.johns@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (64, 'Alexys', 'Wiza', '627-746-6018', 'kassandra32@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (65, 'Abe', 'Mayert', '04786860466', 'edna17@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (66, 'Rossie', 'Stehr', '492.681.4815', 'dsteuber@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (67, 'Pete', 'Herzog', '445.752.0656', 'guillermo28@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (68, 'Karolann', 'McClure', '07992288352', 'ivon@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (69, 'Chelsea', 'Volkman', '347.845.5423x826', 'qskiles@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (70, 'Sedrick', 'Simonis', '884-285-4733x4751', 'kuhlman.tyler@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (71, 'Jamaal', 'Schumm', '(590)897-5602', 'pryan@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (72, 'Clementina', 'Haag', '1-741-084-7615', 'jmann@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (73, 'Jarrod', 'Boehm', '(470)791-9587', 'wunsch.thurman@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (74, 'Francis', 'Lakin', '(879)314-7455', 'wmante@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (75, 'Destin', 'Hegmann', '+38(3)5095401481', 'treutel.evie@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (76, 'Elise', 'Morar', '(413)829-6624', 'simone93@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (77, 'Brennon', 'Hilll', '156.207.3304x7596', 'elsie.muller@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (78, 'Jefferey', 'McLaughlin', '1-991-092-2904', 'boyer.ceasar@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (79, 'Ashley', 'Witting', '1-214-447-4193', 'juana15@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (80, 'Hardy', 'Jones', '(608)353-5317x92341', 'qchristiansen@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (81, 'Asa', 'Lubowitz', '407.742.3356', 'streich.samir@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (82, 'Lois', 'Osinski', '410-768-3515', 'wisoky.caroline@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (83, 'Leopold', 'Nolan', '738.156.3224', 'tyson.ruecker@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (84, 'Alana', 'Hirthe', '875-768-9095', 'herman.reinhold@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (85, 'Darwin', 'Hilpert', '253-344-4728', 'zjacobs@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (86, 'Verlie', 'Kuhic', '961.242.8112', 'hilton.langworth@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (87, 'Giuseppe', 'Heller', '1-584-135-4675x42568', 'lang.imani@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (88, 'Bobby', 'Kihn', '(460)616-4688x02065', 'linda07@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (89, 'Destiney', 'Auer', '826-638-7776', 'zklein@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (90, 'Dawson', 'Marvin', '116.660.9381x388', 'quincy.batz@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (91, 'Marcus', 'Nolan', '01257852052', 'adicki@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (92, 'Jamir', 'Hegmann', '498.875.7905', 'fupton@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (93, 'Sierra', 'Heaney', '00504574720', 'santino55@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (94, 'Lewis', 'Smitham', '017.237.1121', 'francisca.nader@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (95, 'Carolyn', 'Nienow', '1-892-701-1906x70832', 'eric.labadie@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (96, 'Vincenzo', 'Waters', '(108)272-5876x7358', 'kenyon09@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (97, 'Thora', 'Hayes', '704.761.5063', 'shanahan.zita@example.org');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (98, 'Domenick', 'Gerhold', '1-224-382-6184x7777', 'bradly98@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (99, 'Sabrina', 'Thiel', '09005685037', 'jayde.rowe@example.net');
INSERT INTO users (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES (100, 'Joannie', 'Kris', '(650)107-2917', 'amani.johnson@example.org');
```

I need a batch file that will run `randomdatausers.sql`, that is to populate table using a batch file.

I don't know what should be the content of that batch file.

I have tried the following (this is the content of my batch file that doesn't work):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\mysql\bin>mysql < randomdatausers.sql
```

Could someone show what should be the working content for a batch file?

Comment: It seems you are missing the name of the database that the sql file will be applied to

Try C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\mysql\bin>mysql -u user -p pass databasename< randomdatausers.sql

Comment: @IvanM, That doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @IvanM, Nothing changes after I run .bat file. Table 'users' doesn't change.

Comment: Have you tried executing the command directly from the cmd first to see if the command is working?

Comment: @IvanM, I have tried that. That gives the error "The system cannot find the file specified". After that, I have tried the following: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\mysql\bin>mysql < C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\randomdatausers.sql" and it runs successfully, but it doesn't change anything that should be changed. So, this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Here is the batch file:

```
mysql -u root -D 'dbname' < randomdatausers.sql
```